# Is there any API to determine the distance between 2 points by Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to determine the distance between 2 points by Google Maps.
These 2 points are given by its' address. Is there any API that I can use for this purpose?

For example, I send 2 addresses to a URI like http://example.com/address1/address2 and it shall return a JSON like

```
{
    'from'         :address1,
    'to'           :address2,
    'distanceByBus':100,
    'straight'     :50
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is - [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

> The Google Maps Distance Matrix API is a service that provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations, based on the recommended route between start and end points.

## URL example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

## JSON return value

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please remove your answer? So that I can remove this question. Seems it's a non-sense question.